# Why does F# interactive console not consider "assert (2=3)" as wrong?

Tags: f#

I send this line to F# interactive console in Visual Studio

```
assert (2=3)
```

To my surprise, the console does not report errors, but

```
val it : unit = ()
```

Similarly, if I run

```
printf ("hello!")

assert (2=3)

printf ("hello2")
```

on an REPL, I got "hellohello2" without any error messages.

How could I make the F# interactive tell me 2=3 is wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under the cover, the `assert` keyword translates to a method call to the `Debug.Assert` method from the .NET library ([see the method documentaiton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.assert?view=netcore-3.1)). This has a conditional compilation attribute `[Conditional("DEBUG")]`, meaning that the call is only included if the symbol `DEBUG` is defined.

By default, this is not the case in F# Interactive. You can do that by adding `--define:DEBUG` to the command line parameters for `fsi.exe`. This will be somewhere in the options of your editor, depending on what you are using. For example, in Visual Studio, you need something like this:

[image]

**EDIT**: How to do something like this if you do not want to modify the command line parameters? This really depends on what exactly behaviour you want. The default behaviour of `assert` is that it shows a message box where you can either terminate the program or ignore the error. You could do that using:

```
open System.Windows.Forms

let ensure msg b = 
  let res = 
    MessageBox.Show("Assertion failed: " + msg + 
      "\n\nDo you want to terminate the exection? Press 'Yes' " + 
      "to stop or 'No' to ignore the error.", "Assertion failed", 
      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
  if res = DialogResult.Yes then exit 42

ensure "Mathematics is broken" (2=3)
```

Comment: Suppose that I prefer to not mess up with the command line parameters for fsi.exe, how can I let F# interactive check a boolean condition and report errors?

Comment: @zell I edited the answer showing one option - but it depends on what exactly behaviour you want.